# how to add django url and function in vue js code

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, frontend, backend

I have a drf view to download the file i dont have knowledge on how to add the url in vue js here is how my code looks like

**views.py**

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def my_view(request,pk):
    data = get_object_or_404(Mymodel,pk)
    response = HttpResponse(
        data.data_file,
        content_type='',
    )
    return response
```

**model.py**

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    datafile = models.FileField(upload_to='',blank=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('myurl/<int:pk>/',views.my_view,name='url_download')
```

**vue.js**

```
downloaddatafile: function (id) {
              alert('TODO: add URL & function to download datafile, file id: ' + id);
            },
```